# How can i design this page in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

how can I design that page in ionic 4? I'm still new to ionic. its a bank app I am building with ionic 4, below is the image of the page.

[image: screenshot of the page]

Comment: that would be us doing work for you ..

Comment: Read / watch tutorials, and then do trial & attempts until you succeed?

Answer (score 1):

You should **start here**, https://ionicframework.com/ read through documentation.

Your app looks like a **tabs** based app so it would be easiest to start with a tabs ionic project.

Therefore, run `ionic start myBankAppName tabs --cordova` to use cordova as your native cross-platform engine or `ionic start myBankAppName tabs --capacitor` to use capacitor for the same purpose.

After that consult the relevant components that you need at https://ionicframework.com/docs/components.

Have fun! ;)

Comment: i know, i just need help with the css and the html, i can do the others

Comment: Would you be interested in paying to have it built for you in Ionic?